# collection.reset not populating with all the models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My Backbone collection calls a fetch like this

```
collection.fetch({data : {product_type: foo, year: bar}, processData: true, success: function(response){
            console.log(response, "response from server");
            collection.reset(response);
        }});
```

In the Chrome console, it shows that the array has six records, but when I inspect the response further, there are actually 0 models in the array. You can see this below by noticing the number 6 in the first line and Array[0] in the last line:

```
MyCollection {length: 6, models: Array[6], _byId: Object, sortField: "date", sortDirection: "DESC"…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_listenId: "l1"
length: 0
model: function (attrs, options) {
models: Array[0]  
//...other details  ommitted...//
```

Furthermore, only 1 of my 6 expected models appears in the view.  Given the above, I thought maybe either 0 or 6 would appear, but there is 1.

Why isn't the collection resetting with all 6 of the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on docs [Collection#fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) I can see that the `success` callback has 3 arguments

```
(collection, response, options)
```

So in your case `response` is a `collection` updated based on `JSON` array from the server, so you don't need to reset it again, instead you reset it with collection means you add clear the collection and add new model which is actually a collection itself. So you may use instead

```
collection.reset(response.models)
```

but I think you should not perform any action on collection within `success` callback, backbone does it for you automatically.